# How do loss functions know for which model to compute gradients in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I am unsure how PyTorch manges to link the loss function to the model I want it to be computed for. There is never an explicit reference between the loss and the model, such as the one between the model's parameters and the optimizer.

Say for example I want to train 2 networks on the same dataset, so I want to utilize a single pass through the dataset. How would PyTorch link the appropriate loss functions to the appropriate models. Here's code for reference:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import shap

# Define a transform to normalize the data
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                              ])
# Download and load the training data
trainset = datasets.MNIST('~/.pytorch/MNIST_data/', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(128, 64),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(64, 10),
                      nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))

model2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(128, 10),
                      nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))

# Define the loss
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
criterion2 = nn.NLLLoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
optimizer2 = optim.SGD(model2.parameters(), lr=0.003)

epochs = 5
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    running_loss_2 = 0
    for images, labels in trainloader:
        # Flatten MNIST images into a 784 long vector
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1) # batch_size x total_pixels

        # Training pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer2.zero_grad()

        output = model(images)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


        output2 = model2(images)
        loss2 = criterion2(output2, labels)
        loss2.backward()
        optimizer2.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        running_loss_2 += loss2.item()

    print(f"Training loss 1: {running_loss/len(trainloader)}")
    print(f"Training loss 2: {running_loss_2/len(trainloader)}")
    print()
```

So once again, how does pytorch know how to compute the appropriate gradients for the appropriate models when `loss.backward()` and `loss2.backward()` are called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you perform *forward* operations using one of your model parameters (or any `torch.tensor` that has attribute `requires_grad==True`), pytorch builds a *computational graph*. When you operate on descendents in this graph, the graph is extended. In your case, you have a `nn.module` called `model` which will have some trainable `model.parameters()`, so pytorch will build a graph from your `model.parameters()` all the way to the loss as you perform the forward operations. The graph is then traversed in reverse during the *backward pass* to propagate the gradients back to the parameters. For  `loss` in your code above the graph is something like

```
model.parameters() --> [intermediate variables in model] -->  output --> loss
                                  ^                                        ^
                                  |                                        |
                               images                                     labels
```

When you call `loss.backward()` pytorch traverses this graph in reverse to reach all trainable parameters (only the `model.parameters()` in this case) and updates `param.grad` for each of them. The `optimizer` then relies on this information gathered during the backward pass to update the parameter.
For `loss2` the story is similar.

The official [pytorch tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py) are a good resource for more in-depth information on this.

Comment: So the computation graph is stored in a sense inside torch's state? whatever loss function I call to backpropagate, that's the one that calculates the derivatives? Does this mean that there can be only a single computation graph at a time (ex. I cannot perform `model(input)` and right after in the next line `model2(input)`? Is only the last computation graph retained?)?

Comment: Internally descendants of trainable tensors have a reference to "where they came from". so when you you write `loss = criterion(output, labels)` then the `loss` tensor will have an attribute `grad_fn` that tells it how to report back the gradients in a backward pass. You can have multiple graphs at the same time and each root node can have multiple descendents. If you have e.g. a trainable `x` and `y=x**2` and `z=2*x+5` then `y` and `z` don't know about each other but both can be used to calculate `dy/dx` and `dz/dx`

Comment: So if there can be multiple graphs at the same time, how do the loss functions link to the appropriate graph? All we do is pass a tensor `output` and a tensor `labels` which have no reference from where they come from (as far as I know, they only contain the values of the output and no info about the models they were produced from). Performing two passes `output1=model(input)` producing 1 graph and `output2=model2(input)` producing another right after, how will `loss1=criterion1(output1, labels)` and `loss2=criterion2(output2, labels)` know for which graph they need to be computed?

Comment: `output` **does** have a reference to its descendants because the function `model()` is just a composition of lower-level pytorch operations that get applied to the parameters one after another. Try printing `output`, you should see a `grad_fn` attribute in it.

Comment: Yes, just caught it, thank you a ton my friend, you've helped me solve a great mystery.

Comment: @hdkrgr Does this mean that the criterion doesn't need to be initialized twice and the same criterion can be applied to the two graphs?